# markdown with plantuml transformed by maven site plugin

Tags: maven, markdown, plantuml, maven-site-plugin

I use maven site plugin to create my sites (of course).
Since short I moved to markdown,
which is very easy, just write `xxx.md` files in folder `markdown`.
Now I started using `plantuml` and want to integrate them into markdown.

```
` ` `plantuml
@startuml
...
@enduml
` ` `
```

Now the created site creates code which is verbatim the plantuml commands.
I want that this is executed.
How can I do that??

I found something close to what I need but not integrated into the site plugin:
https://gist.github.com/noamtamim/f11982b28602bd7e604c233fbe9d910f.